# font awesome icons not aligning with Bootstrap

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I am designing an About page in my Angular 8 application. I am utilizing font awesome and bootstrap 4.

The font awesome is not centering (aligning) correctly with bootstrap. Here's my code if someone could please guide!

```
<!--==========================
  About Us Section
============================-->

<section id="about">
  <div class="container">
    <header class="section-header">

      <h3 *ngIf="!showSpanish">About Us</h3>
      <h3 *ngIf="showSpanish">Sobre nosotros</h3>
      <p *ngIf="!showSpanish">
        Here goes Description!
      </p>
      <p *ngIf="showSpanish">
        ¡Aquí va la descripción de!
      </p>
      <div class="input-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary p-1 mr-1" (click)="useLanguage('en')" type="button">English</button>
        <button class="btn btn-success  p-1 ml-1" (click)="useLanguage('es')" type="button">Espaniol</button>
      </div>

    </header>
    <div class="row about-cols">
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
        <div class="about-col">
          <div class="img">
            <img src="http://.../img/SV01.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">

            <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i></div>

          </div>
          <h2 class="title" *ngIf="!showSpanish">Background</h2>
          <h2 class="title" *ngIf="showSpanish">Antecedentes</h2>
          <p *ngIf="!showSpanish">
            What is a Plan?
            Some text
          </p>
          <p *ngIf="showSpanish">
            What is a Plan?
            Some text in spanish
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded" data-wow-delay="0.1s">
        <div class="about-col">
          <div class="img">
            <img src="http://.../Content/img/SV02.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">

            <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-book-open"></i></div>
          </div>
          <h2 class="title" *ngIf="!showSpanish">What We Do?</h2>
          <h2 class="title" *ngIf="showSpanish">Que hacemos</h2>

          <p *ngIf="!showSpanish">
            Some text
          </p>
          <p *ngIf="showSpanish">
            some text
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
        <div class="about-col">
          <div class="img">
            <img src="http://.../Content/img/SV03.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></div>
          </div>
          <h2 class="title" *ngIf="!showSpanish">Our Mission and Vision</h2>
          <h2 class="title" *ngIf="showSpanish">Nuestra misión y visión</h2>
          <p *ngIf="!showSpanish">
            some text
          </p>
          <p *ngIf="showSpanish">
            Some text
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section><!-- #about -->
```

For example, 'fas fa-tachometer-alt' is not centered in the 'bg-white rounded'
Similarly "fas fa-book-open", and eye are not centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already set a class on the icon.

```
<div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></div>
```

Just set a negative margin for the icon class in your css. The value will probebly be a round number, but you need to try it out or find through the inspector which margin, padding or element is causing the shift.

Something like:

```
.icon {
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

Should do the trick

Comment: .icon {
  padding-left: 4px !important;
  padding-right: 4px !important;
}  inspected DOM using dev tools and it worked